# Unwrapping optionals for max of a 2D array in swift

Tags: array, swift, optional

I'm working in swift and I've got a custom class `Array2D` to handle fixed-width, two-dimensional arrays of integers. What I'm trying to do is write a simple, ideally-elegant function `max() -> Int?` to behave the same way as for a 1-D array: return `nil` if the array is empty, or else the maximum value in the array. I make no promises about the array contents being positive.

For the sake of simplicity, I'm writing these functions as freestanding rather than parts of a class here.

Broadly speaking, I'm trying to do this:

```
func max(array: [[Int]]) -> Int? {
  set up a variable for maximum value maxSoFar
  for row in array {
    if row.max() > maxSoFar { maxSoFar = row.max() }
  }
  return maxSoFar
}
```

What I'm struggling with is avoiding lots of nested optional handling: I have to handle the `Int?` returned by `max` for each row of the array, and it looks like I'll need `maxSoFar` to be an `Int?` as well, since I don't want to initialize it to zero since all the entries in the array could be negative.

So, a few options:

```
func max1(array: [[Int]]) -> Int? {
  if array.count == 0 || array[0].count == 0 { return nil }
  var maxval: Int = array[0][0]
  for row in array {
    if let rowmax = row.max() {
      if rowmax > maxval { maxval = rowmax }
    }
  }
  return maxval
}
```

```
func max2(array: [[Int]]) -> Int? {
   var maxval: Int?
   for row in array {
     guard let rowmax = row.max() else {
       return nil
     }
     guard let temp = maxval else {
       maxval = rowmax
       continue
     }
     if rowmax > temp {
        maxval = rowmax
     }
    }
    return maxval
```

Thoughts? Alternatives? I'd be delighted to learn a better way to handle this.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review!

Comment: Thanks! Pleasure to be here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first method does not work correctly if the first row is empty:

```
print(max1(array: [[], [1, 2], [-3]])) // nil
```

This is difficult to salvage while avoiding an optional for the current `maxval`.

Your second method returns `nil` if any row is empty:

```
print(max2(array: [[1, 2], [], [3, 4]])) // nil
```

`guard` is a useful language feature to avoid the “optional pyramid of doom,” or to “early exit” in exceptional cases. But in your `max2()` function it makes the program flow difficult to understand (and introduced an error, as we saw above). With plain old `if-let-else` it would look like this:

```
func max2(array: [[Int]]) -> Int? {
    var maxval: Int?
    for row in array {
        if let rowmax = row.max() {
            if let temp = maxval {
                if rowmax > temp { maxval = rowmax }
            } else {
                maxval = rowmax
            }
        }
    }
    return maxval
}
```

But actually the (explicit) handling of all the special cases of an empty array or empty rows can be avoided completely!

The [`Sequence.joined()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/2431985-joined) can be applied to the nested array, it returns a (lazily evaluated) sequence of all concatenated rows.

This simplifies the implementation to

```
func max2D(array: [[Int]]) -> Int? {
    return array.joined().max()
}
```

Or more generic, for nested arrays of *comparable* elements:

```
func max2D<T>(array: [[T]]) -> T? where T: Comparable {
    return array.joined().max()
}
```

You may also consider if it is worth defining a function for that purpose, if you also can call

```
let myMax = my2DArray.joined.max()
```

directly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess I didn't make it clear that elsewhere in this class I enforce the fixed-width 2D array requirement, thus the "single empty row" errors. Your answers are substantially nicer than my original thoughts, so I really appreciate your help!